# Wire color standards for ceiling fan and lights, power from the switch in the USA

Tags: wiring

I'm wiring a brand new ceiling fan, and I'm curious if there's a color standard for which wire controls the fan vs the lights? Power runs to the switch, then to the fan. The run from the switch to the fan is 14/3 with white, black, red, and copper. White (Neutral) and copper (Ground) are easy, but is there a standard for which of red and black controls the lights and which controls the fan?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an end all standard for wire colors, especially with all the DIYers running around.
If the fan will be controlled by the pull chain, it would be likely to have the black feed pigtailed to the switch and to the black going to the fan box to control the fan motor. Then the red would go from the switch to the fan box as a switched hot to control the light. The white wires would be wire nutted together in the switch box and the white wire at the fan box would be connected to the white wire from the fan. If there were double switches to control the fan and the light separately, then the black wire would be pigtailed to both switches and the black and red would be connected each to a switch. Then at the fan box either black or red could be connected to the motor and light of the fan.

Comment: I'm using a switch that has separate controls for the light and fan (Essentially two switches, just only takes up one gang.) The wiring will be one hot into the dual switch, two switched hots out (One dim-able for the lights, one fan controlled), a bundled neutral, and the ground. The fan is pull-chain, but I will be trimming the chains short and only using the wall controls. 

Sounds like if there isn't a standard, I'll just pick one and make sure it's consistent throughout the house as I add more fans. Thanks!

Comment: @MSiegmund  Good plan and don't trim the chain too short... you might want to use it some day.